# Testing Scrapy on GitHub with GitHub Actions

Tags: scrapy, github-actions

I'm trying to figure out a way to run Scrapy Spider Contracts using local copy of a **simple HTML website** on GitHub and I could use some help.

On a development machine I'm guessing solution would be to run Apache or something similar and then just test website as http://127.0.0.1/website.html.

But how should it look on GitHub? I'm talking about GitHub actions to be precise, so the Spider could be tested automatically after each pull request is created. Tested using known website. Also, the whole repository is private so the solution has to be contained within project.

The only solution I can think of is run Apache server as a Docker image. But I have to major problems with this:

1. It might be too resource expensive to spin-up Apaches server for each PR.
2. Can I have within single GitHub workflow Python and Docker image with Apache? So far I have been using one or another.

I'd appreciate any suggestions how to best approach this.

Comment: Learn to use mock objects and monkeypatching